# How to use clearInterval() and then make changes to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have this code and the problem I have is that I want to stop the loop and then replace the text 'Done!' that comes from the sms-loader.php script with the "textnew" string. Problem is that the loop occurs one more time so the text in the div.checkstatus field is again replaced by the calling php script.

The strange thing is that I see the log message and again I get a new (and final) request, although the ordering is the opposite (first stop then replace text()) in my script. I need to understand why this is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var interval = "";

$('.checkstatus').each(function(){
    var msgid = $(this).data('msg')
        $this = $(this),
        hid = $this.data('history'),
        textnew = '<a href="sms-dstatus.php?id='+msgid+'&sid=' +hid+ '&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=430&amp;width=770" title="Delivery Status" class="thickbox"><img src="../template/icons/supermini/chart_curve.png" alt="status" width="16" height="16" /></a>';

    interval = setInterval(function() {
    $this.load('../pages/sms-loader.php?id='+msgid);

        // stop the loop
        if($this.text()=='Done!'){
            // stop it
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(textnew);
            $this.html(textnew); /// this line is the problem
        }

    }, 5000); // 5 secs

});
});
```

Comment: this.html() should be $this.html()

Comment: THank you Matthew, this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the "tip" to look better the $.ajax function and I had better control for sure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var interval = "";

$('.checkstatus').each(function(){
    var msgid = $(this).data('msg')
        $this = $(this),
        that = $this,
        hid = $this.data('history'),
        refreshimg = '<img src="../template/icons/smalls/10.png"/>';
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
    //$this.load('../pages/sms-loader.php?id='+msgid);
    $.ajax({
            url: "../pages/sms-loader.php",
            type: "GET",
            data:{id:+msgid},
            success: function(data) {
                if($this.text()=='Done!'){
                clearInterval(interval);
                }else{
                $this.html(data);
                }
              }

    }).done(function(){
        if($this.text()=='Done!'){
        console.log(refreshimg);
        $this.empty().html(refreshimg).show();
        clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });

    }, 5000); // 5 secs

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a "var" before "interval", to mark it as local..

Comment: Noop. Didn't change a thing I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'html'" and then again I get this error and THEN again one more call to the php script.

Comment: You cannot use "this" in the context .. save the this in a local var (e.g. var t=this;)

Comment: Or use $this s you declared it before

Comment: I fixed that. I don't get any error now, but again its looping one more time and replaces this.html(textnew).

Comment: A generally tip: Look at the jQuery ajax function .. this would give a cleaner code ..

Comment: i think this is because the ajax function is taking more than 5 sec to execute. ie by the time the ajax response returns the setInterval is being called again

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asychronous, so while the request is being made your other code is going to fire... ahead of the data being returned. I'm not 100% understanding the goal but following outline of how to use the AJAX success callback should help

```
$this.load('../pages/sms-loader.php?id='+msgid, function(){

   /* AJAX complete and new html exists, run code here for after load-*/
   /* I believe you want to run clearInterval here */
});
```

See Reference docs for `load()`  : http://api.jquery.com/load/